# Logstash filter parse json file result a double fields

Tags: json, logstash

I am using the latest ELK (Elasticsearch 1.5.2 , Logstash 1.5.0, Kibana 4.0.2)
I have a question that

sample .json

```
{ "field1": "This is value1", "field2": "This is value2" }
```

longstash.conf

```
input {
   stdin{ }
}

filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
                add_field =>
                {
                        "field1" => "%{field1}"
                        "field2" => "%{field2}"
                }
        }
}

output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   elasticsearch {
      host => "localhost"
      index => "scan"
   }
}
```

Output:

```
{
       "message" => "{ \"field1\": \"This is value1\", \"field2\": \"This is value2\" }",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-05-07T06:02:56.088Z",
          "host" => "myhost",
        "field1" => [
        [0] "This is value1",
        [1] "This is value1"
    ],
        "field2" => [
        [0] "This is value2",
        [1] "This is value2"
    ]
}
```

My question is 1) why the field result appear double in the result? 2) If there is nested array , how is it should reference in the logstash configure?

Thanks a lot!

..Petera

Comment: It is better to ask one thing per question. The second question seems to be without an example and therefore hard to understand. As for the first question, you add a field with the same name, this results in an array. Try it without the add_field, you'll most likely get what you want.

Comment: Jettro, thanks for Comment!  Should I put q2 with example here or ask another question with example?

Comment: I would remove question 2 from here and make it a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what the json filter does. When you process a field through the json filter it will look for field names and corresponding values.

In your example, you have done that with this part:

```
filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
```

Then you have added a field called "field1" with the content of field "field1", since the field already exists you have just added the same information to the field that was already there, it has now become an array:

```
                add_field =>
                {
                        "field1" => "%{field1}"
                        "field2" => "%{field2}"
                }
        }
}
```

If you simplify your code to the following you should be fine:

```
filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}
```

I suspect your question about arrays becomes moot at this point, as you probably don't need the nested array, and therefore, won't need to address it, but in case you do, I believe you can do this like so:

```
[field1][0]
[field1][1]
```